# Connect versions of .net mysql issues?

Tags: c#, mysql

I installed mysql-connect 6.64 in my system and my sql version is 5.50  then we are accessing mysql successfully.but not able to connect mysql version 5.24 .why this is it version of mysql problem or ?

please tell me why i am getting  while conencting mysql from .net

```
unable to connect any hosts"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts
```

Comment: Please post the code in question if you want assistance. Have you tried to upgrade the installation of MySQL by chance?  Its not clear if its actually working at all or not please claifiy the question.  This honestly sounds like a configuration problem.

Comment: which version of mysql-connector in .net will support for mysql version 5.24.please tell me ...